# How to obtain $(a \cdot b)^2 - (a \land b)^2 = a^2b^2$ and why $(a \land b)=|a||b||\sin(\phi)|$ if $(a \land b)^2=-|a|^2|b|^2\sin^2(\phi)$? (GA)

Tags: geometric-algebras

I read in Wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector) that antisymmetric part of geometric product can be represent as $(a \land b)$ and $(a \cdot b)^2 - (a \land b)^2 = a^2b^2$

I have 2 questions:

1. How to derive $(a \cdot b)^2 - (a \land b)^2 = a^2b^2$ ?

solved: $(ab)(ba) = (a \cdot b)^2 - (a \land b)^2$

2. Why $(a \land b)=|a||b||\sin(\phi)|$ if  $(a \land b)^2=-|a|^2|b|^2\sin^2(\phi)$?

solved: $B=(a \land b)=|a|b||sin(\phi)|B*$ where $B*$ is unit bivector.

Thanks.

Comment: What work have you done in trying to answer these questions by yourself?

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff First question is solved.  $(ab)(ba) = (a \cdot b)^2 - (a \land b)^2$

Comment: There is no way $(a\wedge b)=|a||b|\sin(\phi)$ as the left-hand side is a bivector and the right-hand side is a real number.

Comment: @ThatoTsabone Second question is solved. $B=(a \land b) = |a||b|sin(\phi)B*$ where $B*$ is unit bivector.

Comment: @Mike_bb Awesome! Maybe fix your question so that someone with a similar question understands.

Comment: Geometric algebra is unnecessarily esoteric obfuscating how simple their ideas are in the end. When it is combined with Wikipedia it gets even worse. $ab=a\cdot b+(a\wedge b)$ is a new operation that adds together scalars and bivectors similarly to Gauss adding real and imaginary numbers. In the GA case we add something that is symmetric in $a,b$ (the scalar $a\cdot b$) with something that is anti symmetric in $a,b$ (the bivector $a\wedge b\,.$)

Comment: Then $$\require{cancel}
(ab)(ba)=(a\cdot b+a\wedge b)(a\cdot b-a\wedge b)=(a\cdot b)^2+\cancel{(a\cdot b)(a\wedge b)}-\cancel{(a\cdot b)(a\wedge b)}-(a\wedge b)^2
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really two questions, first.

### Square.

Given

$\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \frac{1}{{2}} \left( { \mathbf{a} \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{b} \mathbf{a} } \right),$

$\mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b} = \frac{1}{{2}} \left( { \mathbf{a} \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{b} \mathbf{a} } \right),$

we have

$\begin{aligned}\left( { \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} } \right)^2 - \left( { \mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b} } \right)^2 &=\frac{1}{{4}} \left( { \mathbf{a} \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{b} \mathbf{a} } \right)^2 - \frac{1}{{4}} \left( { \mathbf{a} \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{b} \mathbf{a} } \right)^2 \\ &=\frac{1}{{4}} \left( { \left( {\mathbf{a} \mathbf{b}} \right)^2 +\left( {\mathbf{b} \mathbf{a}} \right)^2+ \mathbf{a} \mathbf{b} \mathbf{b} \mathbf{a}+ \mathbf{b} \mathbf{a} \mathbf{a} \mathbf{b} } \right)-\frac{1}{{4}} \left( { \left( {\mathbf{a} \mathbf{b}} \right)^2+\left( {\mathbf{b} \mathbf{a}} \right)^2- \mathbf{a} \mathbf{b} \mathbf{b} \mathbf{a}- \mathbf{b} \mathbf{a} \mathbf{a} \mathbf{b} } \right) \\ &=\frac{1}{4} \left( {  2 \mathbf{a}^2 \mathbf{b}^2} \right)-\frac{1}{4} \left( { - 2 \mathbf{a}^2 \mathbf{b}^2} \right) \\ &= \mathbf{a}^2 \mathbf{b}^2.\end{aligned}$

Assuming a Euclidean vector space, you may introduce a bivector norm defined as

$\left\lVert {\mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b}} \right\rVert = \sqrt{ -\left( { \mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b}} \right)^2 },$

then we may write this identity is a slightly prettier form

$\mathbf{a}^2 \mathbf{b}^2 = \left( { \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} } \right)^2 + \left\lVert {\mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b}} \right\rVert{}^2.$

This is a generalization of the 3D identity

$\left\lVert \mathbf{a} \right\rVert{}^2 \left\lVert \mathbf{b} \right\rVert{}^2 = \left( { \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} } \right)^2 + \left\lVert {\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}} \right\rVert{}^2.$

### Trig relations.

For the second question, let's express one vector in terms of length and direction, say

$\mathbf{a} = \left\lVert {\mathbf{a}} \right\rVert \mathbf{\hat{a}},$

and then express the second vector as a scaled rotation of that unit vector
$ \mathbf{\hat{a}} $.  That is

$\mathbf{b} = \left\lVert {\mathbf{b}} \right\rVert \mathbf{\hat{a}} e^{i\theta},$

where $ \theta $ is the angle from $ \mathbf{a} $ to $ \mathbf{b} $, and

$i = (\mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b})/\left\lVert {\mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b}} \right\rVert,$

is the unit pseudoscalar for the plane containing $ \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} $, and is oriented "from" $ \mathbf{a} $ "to" $ \mathbf{b} $ as sketched below.
Also note that we did not need to use half angle sandwiched rotors, since we are rotating in the plane formed by the span of the two vectors.

[image: bivector in plane of two vectors]

You can now expand the product $ \mathbf{a} \mathbf{b} $ as

$\begin{aligned}\mathbf{a} \mathbf{b} &= \left\lVert {\mathbf{a}} \right\rVert \mathbf{\hat{a}} \left\lVert {\mathbf{b}} \right\rVert \mathbf{\hat{a}} e^{i\theta} \\ &= \left\lVert {\mathbf{a}} \right\rVert \left\lVert { \mathbf{b} } \right\rVert \mathbf{\hat{a}} \mathbf{\hat{a}} e^{i\theta} \\ &= \left\lVert {\mathbf{a}} \right\rVert \left\lVert { \mathbf{b} } \right\rVert e^{i\theta} \\ &= \left\lVert {\mathbf{a}} \right\rVert \left\lVert { \mathbf{b} } \right\rVert \left( { \cos\theta + i \sin\theta } \right).\end{aligned}$

Scalar and bivector grade selections show that

$\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \left\lVert {\mathbf{a}} \right\rVert \left\lVert { \mathbf{b} } \right\rVert \cos\theta,$

and

$\mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b} = \left\lVert {\mathbf{a}} \right\rVert \left\lVert { \mathbf{b} } \right\rVert i \sin\theta.$

In particular, we have

$\left( { \mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b}} \right)^2 = \left\lVert {\mathbf{a}} \right\rVert^2 \left\lVert { \mathbf{b} } \right\rVert^2 (-1) \sin^2\theta,$

and

$\left\lVert { \mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b}} \right\rVert^2 = \left\lVert {\mathbf{a}} \right\rVert^2 \left\lVert { \mathbf{b} } \right\rVert^2 \sin^2\theta,$

or

$\left\lVert { \mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b}} \right\rVert = \left\lVert {\mathbf{a}} \right\rVert \left\lVert { \mathbf{b} } \right\rVert \left\lvert { \sin\theta } \right\rvert,$

which is what you meant to write.